# Google sheets - Optimisation of function to create notes in a range (very slow)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, optimization, google-sheets

I have a script to create Notes on cells based on their value, but the process is very slow and my sheet has 15000 rows. Is it possible to reduce the delay by optimizing the script ?

PS : I use spreadsheet with french parameters.

```
function InsertCellsNotes(){

  var plage = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection().getActiveRange(); 
  var Notes = plage.getValues();
  var NB_lines = Notes.length;
 
  for (var i=1; i<NB_lines+1; i++){  // ajouter +1 !
    var myCell = plage.getCell(i, 1);
    var cellValue = Notes[i-1];

    if (cellValue == "#N/A" || ""){   } 
    else {  myCell.setNote(cellValue); }
 } 
}
```

An example of the sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lu7dEoyO2NDHV4phXeh8DAAkbBuQG5EQWwMA6SJDP1A/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

Two tricks:

- Avoid unnecessary api calls when possible. You are iteratively using methods that interact with the spreadsheet file and that causes extreme delays. Read [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).
- When you use `null` as an argument for `setNote`, no note is set. We can take advantage of this and construct an array by using the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. Namely, if the value is `#N/A` or blank `""`, assign `null` to the element, otherwise take the value of the cell:

  `var notes = rng.getValues().flat().map(v=>[v=="#N/A" || ""?null:v]);`

This will allow you to get rid of the `for` loops but also create an array that can directly be used in the [setNotes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotesnotes) function: `rng.setNotes(notes);`

### Solution - active range:

Select (with your mouse) a particular range and insert notes (depending on the condition):

```
function InsertCellsNotes(){
   var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
   var notes = rng.getValues().flat().map(v=>[v=="#N/A" || ""?null:v]);
   rng.setNotes(notes);
}
```

### Solution - predefined range:

This is a more static approach. You define a particular sheet `"Sheet1"` and for all the cells in column `B` (until the last row with content of the sheet) you insert notes (depending on the condition):

```
function InsertCellsNotes(){
   var plage = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   var rng = plage.getRange(1,2,plage.getLastRow(),1);
   var notes = rng.getValues().flat().map(v=>[v=="#N/A" || ""?null:v]);
   rng.setNotes(notes);
}
```

Comment: You really did ! Could you please just give a link ressource to the flat() method ?

Comment: @Nad there you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat