# Google sheets automatic Notes [with onEdit() function] on cells' values resulting from formulas

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-statements

Is it possible to create automatic **Notes** based on cells variable values resulting from formulas ?

For example A1=stxt(B1;1;4) gives "some" with B1=sometext (variable value), so that A1's Note would be "some"
And a second question : how to add at least a third condition for exceptions treatment in

```
mySelection.getValues().flat().map(v=>[v=="/" || ""?null:v]); // or #N/A or #VALUE!
```

I didn't neither succeed having many OR conditions in one single code line so that I have to put many if statements like here :

```
     var excludedCols = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14];
     // because if(cellule.substring(0,1) = "C"||"E"||"G"||"I"||"K"||"M"){ is not working
     if (col > 2 && col < 23){
       if (e.range.getRow() > 1){
         if (excludedCols.indexOf(col) == -1){ }
       }
     }
```

PS : These questions come from my previous one answered here : [Google sheets - Optimisation of function to create notes in a range (very slow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65603752/google-sheets-optimisation-of-function-to-create-notes-in-a-range-very-slow/65604007)

Here's an illustrating sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xj5PMIQxvTNhq1gNiFf5SOwzxTH5LtY-NkHydU8Ptuk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: NB : I use sheet with French parameters

Comment: NB 2 : the case study is in an onEdit() function which is only effective when cells values are manually edited but not by relative values changed by a function inside that cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **onEdit() function which is only effective when cells values are**
> **manually edited but not by relative values changed by a function**
> **inside that cells**

- You are trying to trigger an `onEdit` function via a formula but that's not how triggers work. The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) states the following:

> The `onEdit(e)` trigger runs automatically when a **user** changes the
> value  of any cell in a spreadsheet.

Namely, `onEdit` triggers are activated only by **user actions**, not by formulas nor scripts.

The workaround would be to modify the current `onEdit` code a little and include a code which will allow you to edit the formulas part when you change the value of the cells that the formula depends on. For example, you will set a note in a cell in `column C` of the `Feuille1` sheet when you edit a cell in the same row in `column A` of `Header 3`:

```
else if(NomFeuilleActive=="Header 3"){
   if(col==1 && row>1){
   e.source.getSheetByName("Feuille1").getRange(row,3).setNote(e.range.getValue());
   }
  }
```

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e){
   var classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var NomFeuilleActive = classeur.getName();
   var mySelection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
   var excludedCols = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
   var cellule = mySelection.getA1Notation();
   var col = e.range.getColumn();
   var row = e.range.getRow(); //new code
  
   if (NomFeuilleActive == "Feuille1"){ // new code
    if (col > 2 && col < 11){
     if (e.range.getRow() > 1){ // if is not 1st line headers (why doesn't it work with substring() == "1" ?!
       if (excludedCols.indexOf(col) == -1){
          var note = mySelection.getDisplayValue();
          mySelection.setNote(note);  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(e.oldValue);
       } 
     }
   }
  }
  //new code
  else if(NomFeuilleActive=="Header 3"){
   if(col==1 && row>1){
   e.source.getSheetByName("Feuille1").getRange(row,3).setNote(e.range.getValue());
   }
  }
  //
  
  var Plage = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C2:I");
  var valeurs = Plage.getValues().flat().map(v=>[v=="#VALUE!" || ""?null:v]); // not working with "#VALUE!" or "#VALEUR!"
  var notes = Plage.getNotes().map(v=>[v=="* %" || ""?null:v]);
  var Tab = [[],[],[]];
  var ToCorrect = [];

  for (i=0; i<notes.length; i++){
   // Tab[1].push([valeurs[i]]);
   // Tab[2].push([notes[i]]);
  
    if (e.range.getNumberFormat() != "0.###############"){
    if (valeurs[i] != notes[i]){ 
        ToCorrect.push(valeurs[i]); // SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(valeurs[i]);
         // SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange("A1")        }  SpreadsheetApp.getRange( 
    }
    }
  }
}
```

Also in your code you had `if (NomFeuilleActive = "Feuille1")` with one `=` (assignment operation) but this evaluates always to `true` and your code would be executed for any sheet name. I adjusted it to `==` which is the equality operator and the proper way to compare two variables.

---

> **how to add at least a third condition for exceptions treatment?**

If you want to exclude many values and have multiple exceptions, then do that:

`mySelection.getValues().flat().map(v=>[["/","","#N/A","#VALUE!","#VALEUR!"].includes(v)?null:v]);`

where you can list in the inner array all the values you want to exclude from setting a note.

Comment: Thank you Marios. Ok, again I didn't well explain, sorry. Yes your function is perfect when I manually lauch the script, but it doesn't work anymore in onEdit() function as you can see there is no Note in C2:C5 in the sheet example.

Comment: Thanks for the multiple exceptions treatment !

Comment: @Nad thanks for your feedback. Please review my updated answer. The issue has to do with the fact that `onEdit` triggers are **not** triggered by formulas but only by user modifications. The workaround that I describe in my answer is to set the note to the formula cell when you edit the cell that changes that formula. See my answer for more details

Comment: Thank you very much Marios, you helped me so much ! Life bless you

Comment: I will attentively look at your all your (edited) solutions to get mine better. My brain is in fire lol

Comment: @Nad I am also learning from answering. Thank you too and happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out by putting into onEdit() the call to the insertNotes() function

```
function onEdit(e){
  var Header3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Header3");
  var Feuille1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Feuille1");
  var valTemp = Feuille1.getRange("N4").getValue();
  Header3.getRange("A2").setValue(valTemp);
 insertnotes(e);
}


 
function insertnotes(e){
   var mySelection = e.range; 
   var excludedCols = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22];
   
   var col = e.range.getColumn(); //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(col);
  
  var DestRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Feuille1").getRange("C2:C5");
                                                       
   var notes = DestRange.getValues();
   DestRange.setNotes(notes); 
}
```